# How to schedule notification for a specific date and time in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to set notification for a specific date and time **(ex: 15/7/2018 02:00:00)** in Android.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried this but not working. GianhTran

Comment: In that case show what you tried and describe (or explain) how it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's not a duplicated question since the Android background and scheduling management changed dramatically on the newer versions; it's not really good practice to use `AlarmManager`.

also, you are not able in most cases.

I recommend using `WorkManager` from the recent jet pack project.
take a look at 
[Schedule tasks with WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

> WorkManager might use JobScheduler, Firebase JobDispatcher, or AlarmManager. You don't need to write device logic to figure out what capabilities the device has and choose an appropriate API; instead, you can just hand your task off to WorkManager and let it choose the best option.

Comment: This is gold! Never knew there's a scheduler from Android Jetpack.